# The Lorentz group in three dimensions; Parity operator?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, spacetime-dimensions, lorentz-symmetry, parity

In three dimensions the Lorentz group is defined as

\begin{align}
\text{O}(2,1)=\{\Lambda\in\text{GL}(3,\mathbb{R}),~~~ \eta=\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda,~~~ \text{det}(\Lambda)=\pm 1\},~~~\eta=\begin{pmatrix} -1&&0&&0\\0&&1&&0\\0&&0&&1\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Is it true that when considered as a real Lie group it can be written as the union of four disconnected pieces;
\begin{align}
\text{O}(2,1)=\big\{\text{SO}^{\uparrow}(2,1),~\mathscr{P}\cdot\text{SO}^{\uparrow}(2,1),&~\mathscr{T}\cdot\text{SO}^{\uparrow}(2,1),~(\mathscr{P}\mathscr{T})\cdot\text{SO}^{\uparrow}(2,1)\big\},\tag{1}\\[5pt]
\mathscr{P}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&&0&&0\\0&&-1&&0\\0&&0&&-1\end{pmatrix},&~~~\mathscr{T}=\begin{pmatrix} -1&&0&&0\\0&&1&&0\\0&&0&&1\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align} 
where 
\begin{align}
\text{SO}^{\uparrow}(2,1)=\{\Lambda\in\text{O}(2,1),~~~\text{det}(\Lambda)=1,~~~\Lambda^0_{~0}\geq 1\}.
\end{align}
I ask this because in four dimensions it is clear that the parity operator $\mathscr{P}\notin \text{SO}^{\uparrow}(3,1)$ since it has determinant -1. However in three dimensions $\mathscr{P}\in\text{SO}^{\uparrow}(2,1)$ as it satisfies all of the above conditions. Does this mean that the Lorentz group in three dimensions is composed of not four but two disconnected pieces;
\begin{align}
\text{O}(2,1)=\big\{\text{SO}^{\uparrow}(2,1),~\mathscr{T}\cdot\text{SO}^{\uparrow}(2,1)\big\}
\tag{2}\end{align}
and $\text{SO}^{\uparrow}(2,1)$ is the component which is connected to the identity?

Comment: Yes, parity in two dimensions is just a rotation by 180 degrees, so it's connected to the identity. You can similarly construct parity in any even dimension as a series of such rotations.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose by even dimensions you mean $n+1$ dimensions where n is even?

Comment: Also, I cannot now say that we choose the branch with det$(\Lambda)=1$ because it preserves the spatial orientation (parity). So what is the physical justification in considering only Lorentz transformations with det$(\Lambda)=1$? Is the only justification that this is the component connected to the identity?

Comment: Sure; also you could say it's the component that preserves the temporal direction.

Comment: The [Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) still has 4 [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component) in any spacetime dimension $\geq 2$.

Comment: You mean disconnected, right @Qmechanic? So my equation (1) and (2)  are both incorrect then?

Comment: I do not think that the spatial inversion $\vec{x} \to -\vec{x}$ in $\mathbb R^2$ has any physical interest. Rather, this other notion of spatial inversion $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$ may be of physical interest...The connected componentes of $O(2,1)$ still are **4**, in view of that inversion...

Comment: @ValterMoretti I see your point. Would I be correct in claiming that the four connected components you mention are 
$$
\text{O}(2,1)=\big\{\text{SO}^{\uparrow}(2,1),~\mathscr{P}\cdot\text{SO}^{\uparrow}(2,1),~\mathscr{T}\cdot\text{SO}^{\uparrow}(2,1),~(\mathscr{P}\mathscr{T})\cdot\text{SO}^{\uparrow}(2,1)\big\},$$
$$
\mathscr{P}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&&0&&0\\0&&1&&0\\0&&0&&-1\end{pmatrix},~~~\mathscr{T}=\begin{pmatrix} -1&&0&&0\\0&&1&&0\\0&&0&&1\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Comment: Where we could define $\mathscr{P}$ to be either diag$(1,1,-1)$ or diag$(1,-1,1)$ it doesn't matter.

Comment: I mean: $SO^{\uparrow}(2,1)$ is closed and connected (the proof relies on the decomposition into a product of exponentials of the elements of that group). Next define ${\cal T}$ as you did and ${\cal S}: (t,x,y) \mapsto (t,x,-y)$.   The sets $SO^{\uparrow}(2,1)$,  ${\cal T}SO^{\uparrow}(2,1)$,  ${\cal S}SO^{\uparrow}(2,1)$, ${\cal S}{\cal T}SO^{\uparrow}(2,1)$ are closed and connected, their union is $O(1,3)$ and are pairwise disconnected because a continuous function changes sign without passing through zero when joining a pair of these sets...